# protractor: webdriverjs commands inside sql query does not see elements

Tags: mysql, protractor

This is so weird. I have a sql query within my it() function.If I put my regular browser clicks inside my it() function but outside of the sql query function, the clicks are processed with no issues. But when I cut/paste those commands and put inside the sql query, I get ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible. Why?

```
    it('test1',function(){
       webElem.click(); //if I put out here, I dont get error

       sql = "UPDATE table users set users = 1";

       db.connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
           if (!err) {
           //if I put webElem.click();in here, I get ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
           }
           else {
                console.log('ERROR ' + err);
           }                 
       });
});
```

Comment: Is it always reliably reproducible?

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce 100%.

Comment: I'm thinking because protractor is acceptance testing, db manipulations should be separated from test code. maybe in the beforeall() instead of in the it()

Comment: Well, yeah, that's a quite correct note, 100% agree with it.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that although protractor makes it look like test code is synchronous, everything is async under the hood.

It is unlikely that the `it` waits for the `db.connection.query` to complete (it is an asynchronous interface).  So the callback you pass that invokes protractor methods gets invoked in a random context.  (Probably during a subsequent `it` or something --- whenever the db is ready.)

If `db.connection.query` returns something that looks like a promise, then you can just return its result as the result of the `it` and things should work.  Otherwise, you need to wrap the db connect in a promise, or use the explicit `done` callback style of `it`:

```
it('test1',function(done){
       sql = "UPDATE table users set users = 1";

       db.connection.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {
           if (!err) {
              // This is safe because this test won't finish until done is invoked.
              webElem.click();
           }
           done(err);
       });
});
```